# How to create a Voice Recoder in Xamarin forms(Android,iOS)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying so hard to do something but i wasn't able to create this.Any one can help me to create a voice recorder in Xamarin forms crossplatform(Android and iOS)

Comment: IOS `AVAudioRecorder` : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder Android: `MediaRecorder` https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using [dependency service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) and add additional code on each platform, these links will help you to implement audio record service for given platforms:

Android : https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/audio/record_audio/

iOS : https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/record_sound/